# Excel VBA To Take Details To Totals Sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have an Excel workbook that has a detail sheet.  I want to from the button press event convert that to a Total sheet, but I am not sure how.  This is how the detail sheet is set-up

```
Employee -- Item -- Amt -- Sale Date
Joe         Hat     10     2017-01-01
Joe         Ball    04     2017-01-02
Joe         Socks   06     2017-01-04
Joe         Cap     11     2017-01-06
```

And I would want the Totals sheet to only show

```
Employee -- Total Sales
Joe         31
```

What VBA would achieve this?

Comment: The most simple thing you can do is to make a SUMIF() formula and to record it with VBA. Or make a pivot table.

Comment: @Vityata - thank you for the tips.  I will work on those and record some VBA to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most simple example:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()
    Range("C1") = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("A1:A4"), "Joe", Range("B1:B4"))
End Sub
```

Further, you may try to set the ranges in the WorksheetFunction to variables and to make it flexible.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Like Vityata suggested, you can simply use a PivotTable.

Select your table.  On Insert tab, select PivotTable.

In the Create PivotTable dialog, your table range should already be selected, so just click OK.

In the PivotTable Fields pane (on right), check Employee, then Amt.  This should put Employee in the Rows area and Amt in the Values area.

In the PivotTable results, rename the "Row Labels" title to "Employee" and "Sum of Amt" To "Total Sales".  Format the Sales column as needed.  Add a Title to cell A1.

When your data is updated, click the "Refresh" button on the PivotTable Analyze tab to refresh the PivotTable.  You also may need to grow the source range using the "Change Data Source" button.  Sometimes it's easier to just set the Table/Range to something like Sheet1!$A:$D, then click the dropdown next to "Employee", select Sort A-Z and for Label Filters select "Does Not Equal" to "(blank)"